# Probability of rolling each face of a fair die twice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

What is the probability of rolling each face of a fair die twice in 12 rolls?

I know that the probability of each face once in 6 rolls is

$$\frac{6!}{6^6}$$

My attempt, by pretending the die has 12 faces then dividing out the orderings that don't matter:

$$\frac{12!}{2^6 6^{12}}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  It may be easier to note that interpreting the $2^6$ as a part of the numerator instead the numerator is the multinomial coefficient $\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right answer, but I'm not sure about "pretending the die has $12$ faces."  I'd rather say, "There are $\binom{12}2$ positions for the two $6$'s, then $\binom{10}2$ positions for the two $5$'s, and so on," arriving at the same answer as you did.